# Angular: Passing data from parent to child with input undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-input

I have created a popup box component with error information (if there is an error).

At the moment I have an interface.

`status-message.ts`

```
export interface Status {
  message: string;
}
```

`login.component.ts` (parent)

```
import { Status } from '../interfaces/status-message';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  statusFailed: boolean = false;
  status: Status;

  login() {
    this.authService.login(formData).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        if (res.status === 'sucsess') {
          console.log('success');
        } else if (res.status = 'failed') {
           this.statusFailed = true;
           this.status.message = res.message
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

`login.component.html`

```
<app-info-box *ngIf="statusFailed" [ngClass]="{ 'error-box': statusFailed}" [status]="status"></app-info-box>
```

`info-box.component.ts` (child)

```
import { Status } from '../interfaces/status-message';

export class InfoBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() status: Status;
}
```

`info-box.component.html`

```
<span> {{status}} </span>
```

Whenever I run this I am getting an error, `core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined` and the child component shows no text, but shows the styling. 
How can I get this working?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to initialize `status` so when you try to do `this.status.message = res.message`, it throws error because `status` is still undefined.

A quick fix is to initialize `status` like following in your login.component class:

```
status: Status = {
   message: ''
}
```